# SASL LOGIN authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6

Tags: java, mysql, dovecot, postfix-mta

CentOS6.6, Postfix, dovecot 2.0.9 and MySQL 5.1.73

dovecot configuration (`/etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext`):

```
driver = mysql    
connect = host=127.0.0.1 dbname=postfix user=root password=lingo

default_pass_scheme = SHA512
password_query = SELECT email as user, password FROM virtual_user WHERE email='%u';
```

MySQL database:

```
mysql> SELECT email as user, password FROM virtual_user WHERE email='lingo.lin1@radicasys.com';
+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| user                     | password                                                                                                   |
+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| lingo.lin1@example.com | 0da3b4b0385c432a800ca15eae1a8485e5f7abad7b70b4e1c2b9cf15f68afd256cedb2029c6f7cec09e1221e6b10142081e1bb8e5c |
+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The password is generated by `commons-codec`, Java code:

```
System.out.println(DigestUtils.sha512Hex("lingo".getBytes()));
//print :0da3b4b0385c432a800ca15eae1a8485e5f7abad7b70b4e1c2b9cf15f68afd256cedb2029c6f7cec09e1221e6b10142081e1bb8e5c
```

Now I wrote some Java-code to authenticate:

```
public static void sendEmail() throws EmailException, GeneralSecurityException {

        SimpleEmail email = new SimpleEmail();
        // smtp host
        email.setHostName("192.168.15.139");
        email.setSmtpPort(25);
        email.setDebug(true);
        // DigestUtils.sha512Hex("lingo".getBytes())
        email.setAuthentication("lingo.lin1@example.com", "lingo");

        email.setStartTLSEnabled(true);
        MailSSLSocketFactory socketFactory = new MailSSLSocketFactory();
        socketFactory.setTrustAllHosts(true);
        Properties propsSSL = email.getMailSession().getProperties();
        propsSSL.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        propsSSL.put("mail.smtp.ssl.checkserveridentity", "false");
        propsSSL.put("mail.smtp.ssl.socketFactory", socketFactory);
        email.addTo("lingo.lin@qamail.rimanggis.com", "John Doe");
        email.setFrom("lingo.lin@radicasys.com", "Me");
        email.setSubject("Test message");
        email.setMsg("This is a simple test of commons-email");
        email.send();
        System.out.println("success");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SendEmailTest.sendEmail();
        // System.out.println(DigestUtils.sha512Hex("lingo".getBytes()));
    }
```

But it fails with following error:

```
Sep 12 13:30:51 localhost dovecot: auth: Debug: sql(lingo.lin1@radicasys.com,192.168.15.243): query: SELECT email as user, password FROM virtual_user WHERE email='lingo.lin1@radicasys.com';
Sep 12 13:30:51 localhost dovecot: auth: Error: sql(lingo.lin1@radicasys.com,192.168.15.243): Password in passdb is not in expected scheme SHA512
Sep 12 13:30:53 localhost postfix/smtpd[1872]: warning: unknown[192.168.15.243]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
Sep 12 13:30:53 localhost dovecot: auth: Debug: client out: FAIL#0115#011user=lingo.lin1@radicasys.com
Sep 12 13:30:53 localhost postfix/smtpd[1872]: lost connection after AUTH from unknown[192.168.15.243]
Sep 12 13:30:53 localhost postfix/smtpd[1872]: disconnect from unknown[192.168.15.243]
```

How can I fix the authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a dovecot configuration issue. Dovecot knows two hash encodings, the "traditional" hex encoding (ie. `SHA512.HEX`) and Base64-encoding (ie. `SHA512.b64`). The latter is more space-efficient when stored as strings and default in Dovecot. An example for generating the hash with `sha512`, `sha512.b64` and `sha512.hex` encodings:

```
$ doveadm pw -p lingo -s sha512
{SHA512}DaO0sDhcQyqADKFerhqEheX3q617cLThwrnPFfaK/SVs7bICnG987AnhIh5rEBQggeG7jlyAL7l+g8iTwo2GFA==
$ doveadm pw -p lingo -s sha512.b64
{SHA512.b64}DaO0sDhcQyqADKFerhqEheX3q617cLThwrnPFfaK/SVs7bICnG987AnhIh5rEBQggeG7jlyAL7l+g8iTwo2GFA==
$ doveadm pw -p lingo -s sha512.hex
{SHA512.HEX}0da3b4b0385c432a800ca15eae1a8485e5f7abad7b70b4e1c2b9cf15f68afd256cedb2029c6f7cec09e1221e6b10142081e1bb8e5c802fb97e83c893c28d8614
```

Use `default_pass_scheme = SHA512.HEX` if you create hex-encoded passwords hashes in Java. The better solution would be to use Dovecot's `{SCHEME}hash` encoding instead of setting the `default_pass_scheme`, though: doing so, you can easily change/upgrade the hash method later without invalidating all user's passwords at once. An example for the hash you used in this scheme:

```
{SHA512.hex}0da3b4b0385c432a800ca15eae1a8485e5f7abad7b70b4e1c2b9cf15f68afd256cedb2029c6f7cec09e1221e6b10142081e1bb8e5c
```

Finally: plain hashing of passwords is *never* save, also not when using large SHA512 hashes. Never store unsalted password hashes, you're vulnerable to rainbow table attacks if the database leaks.

Comment: If the answer solved your issue, consider selecting the checkmark on the left. Also have a look at the [FAQ].

Comment: hi Jens Erat, how to generate sha512 by java ??

Comment: and if i use sha512.b64, what is the default_pass_scheme 's value?

Comment: Please ask another question on how to calculate those hash sums, this is not really related with this question. You can either use `sha512` or `sha512.b64` if you store Base64-encoded hashes.

Answer (score 0):

i generate by this code:

```
private String SHA(final String strText, final String strType) {
        String strResult = null;
        if (strText != null && strText.length() > 0) {
            try {
                MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance(strType);
                messageDigest.update(strText.getBytes());
                byte byteBuffer[] = messageDigest.digest();
                StringBuffer strHexString = new StringBuffer();
                for (int i = 0; i < byteBuffer.length; i++) {
                    String hex = Integer.toHexString(0xff & byteBuffer[i]);
                    if (hex.length() == 1) {
                        strHexString.append('0');
                    }
                    strHexString.append(hex);
                }
                strResult = strHexString.toString();
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return strResult;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EncryptUtils et=new EncryptUtils();
        String pas=et.SHA512("lingo");
        System.out.println("{SHA512.HEX}"+pas);
    }
```